# Android:Returning from Rx Android Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-android

I have one class method that is returning Observable. The observable contain the authorization key which is needed to pass to post method. I am able to return value from one class but Could not catch it in another class on time. I was reading and people have used Observable.blocking.first which blocks current thread which is not good approach. Any know how to catch it in another class. Here is my code:

Class returning observable:

```
public class GetAuthenticationToken {
     String authentication_token;
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://abc.def.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
        GetTokenInterface service = retrofit.create(GetTokenInterface.class);

        Observable<String> response_call = service.getToken1(setAPI_KEY, getaccesstoken);
        String savedToken;
        @CheckResult
        public Observable<String> getToken() {
            return service.getToken1(setAPI_KEY, getaccesstoken)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .doOnNext(new Action1<String>() {
                        public void call(String token) {
                            savedToken = token;
                        }
                    }) 
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        }

        public String getSavedToken() {
            return savedToken;
        }
}
```

But dont know to catch it here on time in another class without blocking thread:

```
  public class Post_To_Api {
GetAuthenticationToken getauthenticationtoken = new GetAuthenticationToken();
        Observable<String> generated_token = getauthenticationtoken.getToken(); //Dont know to get it here on time without blocking thread
                    generated_token.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
                            .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted() {

                                    System.out.print("Complete");
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                                    System.out.print("Fail");
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onNext(String token) {
                                    authentication_token = token; //getting correct value here
                                }
                            });

    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Refresh token?

Comment: I am trying to return value from gettoken() method and use it in another class

Comment: Be more explicit.

Comment: I dont know how to get the returned value on time

Comment: @FlorescuGeorgeCătălin See my edits. I dont know how to get value on time in Post_To_Api class

Comment: You don't need to make a class in order to create an Observable. You can create observable where ever you want.

Comment: @FlorescuGeorgeCătălin yeah you are right but problem is I need that token for posting data but I am not getting it on time to post the data as onNext is asynchronous

Comment: I don't understand anything that you want to do. Save your token into shared preferences or chain requests using `flatMap`, `contactMap`, etc.

Comment: You could create an interface, then pass in a parameter to `getToken()`, upon which you "callback" that interface

Comment: @cricket_007 can you please give an example or do you have example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to keep doing things asynchronous instead of making it blocking.

```
MyApiServide myApiService = // Create your retrofit API service 

public Observable<SomeApiResult> requestApiItem() { 
    return getApiToken()
       .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<SomeApiResult>>() {
           public Observable<SomeApiResult> call(String token) {
               return myApiService.requestItem(token);
           }
       })
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
}


public Observable<String> getApiToken() {
    // get token from API as you have
}

// Were you use the API
requestApiItem()
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<SomeApiResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            System.out.print("Complete");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            System.out.print("Fail");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(SomeApiResult apiResult) { 
            myView.setText(apiResult.someValue); // or whatever you want to do with result.
        }
    });
```